# Starcraft 2 installer: invisible buttons followed by stuck progress bar

Tags: installation, wine

[This is my Wine output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/730656/). It appears I can click where the INSTALL button would be and it goes to the progress bar screen. The Terran guy appears on the top but the progress bar never moves. Any support on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing SC2.  I read online that the buttons are clickable but invisible, so you can progress through the install if you can figure out where the buttons are.  I found this to be true, but was never able to finish the install this way because I couldn't find the invisible button on the install page with Reynor's revolver in the background.

I haven't had a chance to try it, but I just found a list of recommended wine-tricks options to install before trying to install SC2 with Wine.  It's at the bottom of the page here:  http://gameolosophy.com/games/adventure/starcraft/starcraft-ii-on-ubuntu-11-04/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, hasn't helped as I am on 64-bit haha think thats why it doesnt work! Darn 32bit always getting the best stuff haha

Comment: @JakeSteele Shouldn't be true for much longer, I think. Microsoft has been pushing 64-bit with Windows for a little while now, and Canonical is making 64-bit the default starting with 12.04 LTS. For the most part, 64-bit gets pretty good support, but this should help clear up the rest of the issues over time as it becomes the new standard.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can install without seeing the buttons. If the installer loads first:

1. Click near top left column. (This will hit install even if its not showing.)
2. Click bottom right, just under the progress bar, a window will pop up to select directory. Chose directroy, press ok.
3. Click under that bottom right, somewhere more near bottom of the window. Still under the right hand side of the progress bar only this time lower. It will activate the installer and just leave it (even if you dont see progress bar move... will take a bit of time)

Walla u will see a popup that SC has installed sucessfully :D Sc I believe closes on its own once its installed and laucnhes the patch manager.

Its easy to watch a youtube of someone installing it on windows to learn where the buttons are located.